# How to filter a GridDB column where there is a particular substring?

Tags: python, database, griddb

I have a database stored in a GridDB container. I need to filter out a column (of codes) and get all the rows where the value has "INB" in its code.
Like this:

```py
'''
 id | codes
----+---------------
  0 | UIGTF0941H9RBD
  1 | UIHGG83G31H9G3
  2 | UIFH3442N2B9HD
  3 | UI41BBINB2B52O
  4 | UI20JUINBHN52N
  5 | UI4207HRHIHCBC

Result:
 id | codes
----+---------------
  3 | UI41BBINB2B52O
  4 | UI20JUINBHN52N

'''
```

I have already checked the SQL documentation on the official website for GriDB, I saw that the `HAVING` clause could be used. But I have no idea how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the `HAVING` statement, you need the `WHERE` statement. You need to do

`SELECT id, codes FROM table_name WHERE LIKE('%INB%', codes)`

This is more of a SQL question tho.